# Entity structure in Core Data with JSON response

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to create the entity diagram for my App and I have some doubts about structure of a concrete entity.
I'm receiving that JSON response:

```
{
    phone: [
      "1111111111",
      "2222222222",
      "3333333333",
    ],
    location: {
        latitude: "39.098765",
        longitude: "-0.1234566"
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to define an array or a dictionary for an entity property. Is this possible? How can I do that?

Comment: You use the Transformable attribute type for arrays and dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer:**

You need to do set Attribute Type to Transformable for both phones and location:

[image: A screenshot from Xcode]

And then in your NSManagedObject subclass you need to make your "phones" and "location" property types from "id" to "NSArray *" and "NSDictionary *" accordingly.

**An explanation:**

It works, because, according to this doc: [Non-Standard Persistent Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1),

> by default, Core Data uses the NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName
>   transformer... You should not specify a name if you are using the
>   default transformer.

And about default transformer: [NSValueTransformer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName)

> The reverse transformation returns an NSData instance created by
>   archiving the value using keyed archiving. The archived object must
>   implement the NSCoding protocol using keyed archiving in order to be
>   unarchived and archived with this transformer.

And NSArray and NSDictionary both confirm to NSCoding protocol, that's why it works out of the box, you don't need to write any custom transformers

Comment: Awesome response! Thanks for the screenshots and the explanation. thanks!!

Comment: np. I hope you won't mind me suggesting a better title for your question (I've made an edit)